# After effect using multiple linear expression based on its value

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I am new to After Effects. I want to write a linear expression on [Audio Amplitude] that is converted from an audio file based on its value as the below:

```
 linear(value,0,15,0,0);
 linear(value,16,20,30,80);
 linear(value,21,30,80,100);
```

So basically I expect when value is between 0  to 15 it becomes 0 when it reach between 16,20 it becomes 30 to 80 ,....
However, it looks it only executes the first linear(0,15) and anything is map to 0,0

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

When expressions are evaluated the **first term that returns a result** will set the value of the property. If you look at your expression line 1 will always return a result - 0. None of the other lines will be executed.

What you need to do is test what the value is and then execute the right function accordingly.

```
if (value <=15){linear(value,0,15,0,0)}; 
if (value <= 20){linear(value,15,20,30,80)};
if(value > 20){linear(value,20,30,80,100)};
```

note that the `linear()` functions on the second and third line have minimum values of 15 and 20, not 16 and 21—consider what would happen if the `value` was 15.5 or 20.5.

What the expression does is only evaluate the first `linear()` function if `value` is in the 0-15 range. If it is that result is returned and the expression stops being evaluated, if not it goes on to the next line, and so on.